# Spring batch merge query with compositeItemWriter

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-batch

In my Spring  batch application, I am running two sql statements on for insert and one for merge. The first query insert the data in a table getting from fixed length file. No issue till this point. My second query is the merge query with some criteria. According to that criteria either it Insert the records or merge the records. Strange thing is that the insertion and updation both happens with single query.
I am using `compositeItemWriter`

```
 @Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<LiborObj> insertW() throws Exception{
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<LiborObj> batchItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    batchItemWriter.setDataSource(oracleDataSource);
    batchItemWriter.setSql(sqlInsert);
    batchItemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<LiborObj>());
    return batchItemWriter;
}

@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<LiborObj> mergeQuery() throws Exception{
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<LiborObj> batchItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    batchItemWriter.setDataSource(oracleDataSource);
    batchItemWriter.setSql(sqlMerge);
    batchItemWriter.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(new ItemPreparedStatementSetter<LiborObj>() {
        @Override
        public void setValues(LiborObj liborObj, PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            ps.setLong(1,jobContainer.getFeedFile().getPkey());
        }
    });
    return batchItemWriter;
}

@Bean
public CompositeItemWriter<LiborObj> compositeItemWriter() throws Exception {
    CompositeItemWriter<LiborObj> compositeItemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter<>();
    compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(insertW(), mergeQuery()));
    return compositeItemWriter;
}
```

My Merge query is

```
merge into  mastertbl 
            using (SELECT * FROM (SELECT rwtbl.*, row_number() OVER( PARTITION BY rwtbl.rate_type, rwtbl.cusip , rwtbl.Submitter_Company ORDER BY rwtbl.pkey) AS row_num FROM    rwtbl WHERE rwtbl.ffid = 2931240 order by rwtbl.pkey) WHERE row_num =1 ) rwtbl
            on (( mastertbl.rate_type = rwtbl.rate_type ) AND ( mastertbl.cusip = rwtbl.cusip ) AND ( mastertbl.Submitter_Company = rwtbl.Submitter_Company ))
            when not matched then
            insert..(,activity_status,).... values... (,'I',)...
    when matched then
            update....activity_status='U'
```

First time when I run this query it should insert the records in master table but it also update the records. As in master table I can see the activity_status 'U'. It means somewhere update statement is also executed but first time when master table is empty there should be always activity_status ='I'

Answer (score 0):

The `CompositeItemWriter` executes all delegates in the same order they were registered.

You can use a [ClassifierCompositeItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html) to classify items to insert or update and route them to the right item writer.

You can also use a custom item writer that invokes either an insert or an update query based on the criteria you need.